# HTMLDOM: How to change text "files selected" from upload button using jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, dom

How to change the text "files selected" on upload button using jquery / javascript ?

[image]

thanks

Note: this is default build-in input file button

Comment: Pls post some sourcecode...

Comment: Take a look at this, might give you some ideas: http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/

Comment: @Chris this is default input file upload button

Comment: @Chaosxmk thanks for the ref, but i don't think that is the solution i've looking for.

Comment: @mysticcode think this text is generated by the browser itself - do you have the option to use some jQuery Plugins or perform ajax-upload?

Comment: @mysticcode The idea was more of hiding the default `4 files selected` and using javascript to create a fake element to give the illusion of doing something similar to `4 files selected` or hide it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do to style and apply custom behaviour to standard upload controls:

I create a fake control, styled as I want and with the needed behaviour, it usually comprises an input type text and a button (or a couple of them).

I include an input type file on the page, but set it's visibility style property to hidden.

I create event listeners for fake control that fires events on hidden upload. This way, when I click on the input type text I can fire a click on input type file. This makes that when I click on my styled input, the upload window to select files is opened.

I control also, that when hidden input type file's value is changed, it's value is also populated to the styled input type text.

So, the idea is basically to cheat users to use an interface that I create to my taste, while behind the courtain the actual ugly input type file is doing the magic.

Comment: i believe there is no other solution than to create custom control and style it with css.